# OrderedDictionary Dataframe objects

Tags: python-3.x

After I process the excel multiple sheets using pandas, I get OrderedDictionary dataframes?

I need to process the value (which is a dataframe with columns and rows) from the ordered dictionary. Each dataframe in the value column has many empty rows. I have to remove them before I process the data.

```py
sheets= list (range(1,21))
satellite_RR=pd.read_excel("file:///C:/Users/sundarsrinivasan1/RR_process/FY2018_2019-Network Risk Register-Satellite-SIT2.xlsm",sheet_name=sheets,skiprows=2,index_col=0)
```